# Android app to OCR and then translate a scanned document

Tags: android, ocr, translation

The title says it all. I have a document which was scanned to PDF and I would like to translate it (German -> English).

Does anyone know of such an app? Preferably free.

Bonus if it can also handle photos with text (but not through the lens, like [Google Translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&hl=en)), however, my search right now is for PDF translation.

---

@Izzy, kennst Du sowas?

Comment: If you still have the original document, [Word Lens](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.questvisual.wordlens.demo) can translate it using the phone camera

Comment: Thanks, Timmy (+1): I am happy enough with Google Translate, but will look at your recommendation. Alas, I do not have the original :-(

Comment: *Word lens* was something coming to my mind as well (see my [app-list on "read and translate"](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_translate), currently in the "footnotes" as a German article being referenced). Being "happy enough with Google Translate": Yes, *Word Lens* should be aquired by them meanwhile – which might be the reason Timmy's link leads to a 404 :) [Google Goggles](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil) might be worth a look as well, and *might* work on stored pictures (I don't remember exactly).